# Maven managed dependencies - resolving ${project.version} from parent pom

Tags: maven, maven-3, build-dependencies

How is placeholder `${project.version}` resolved for managed properties from parent pom? I've expected that it is resolved globally, so when the parent pom has version 2, `${project.version}` would also be resolved to version 2.

In parent pom I have:

```xml
<groupId>my.group</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>2</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>dep</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In child I use

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>2</version>
</parent>
<version>1</version>
<artifactId>child</artifactId>
```

But the artifact `my.group.dep.1.jar` is used, instead of `my.group.dep.2.jar`. So the placeholder is resolved to the version of the project **using** the managed dependency, and not those of the project **defining** the dependency.

Is that expected behaviour? I'm using **maven 3.0.4.**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to skip `<version>` tag in child, but keep the `<parent><version> ... </parent>` tag.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance

> One factor to note is that these variables are processed after
>   inheritance as outlined above. This means that if a parent project
>   uses a variable, then its definition in the child, not the parent,
>   will be the one eventually used.

Comment: What if I don't want child to have the same version as parent? Typically, if they don't release at the same pace

Comment: @Juh_ then look into the parent pom, to check the name of the desired version property which you will override in your own pom.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starter-parent